# Only annotation mapping is supported by Maker Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-8

I have changed the configuration of my Symfony project to use PHP attributes with Doctrine in my Entities. I was really happy about this and wanted to give it a try.

I have changed my `doctrine.yaml` from `annotation` to `attribute`

```yaml
 orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

and use attributes in my entities

```php
#[ORM\Entity(UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id()]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue()]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private ?int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "string", length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "json")]
    private array $roles = [];
}
```

With this configuration my `php bin/console do:sc:up -f` works well.

But when I try to generate a new entity with `php bin/console make:entity` I get this error:

> [ERROR] Only annotation mapping is supported by make:entity, but the
> App\Entity\Toto class uses a different
> format. If you would like this command to generate the properties & getter/setter methods, add your mapping
> configuration, and then re-run this command with the --regenerate flag.

It seems like it's not possible yet to use maker to generate entity with attribute.
Does anyone have found a way to fix this issue or do we just have to wait a new release?

For now I'm using:

```
"doctrine/annotations": "1.13.1"
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.4.2",
"doctrine/orm": "2.9.3"
"symfony/maker-bundle": "1.31.1",
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, it's not supported. There is [an issue](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/892) created asking for this, although I'm 120% sure that the developers *already know* about PHP attributes, and this feature will get done whenever possible.

In the meantime, you can create your entities manually, without using maker (not that hard), or even use something like [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) to convert Annotations to Attributes. There is [a built-in rule](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#annotationtoattributerector) for that.